# Using Kendo Mvc Grid as Mvc EditorTemplate

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to use the Kendo Mvc Grid as a Mvc EditorTemplate like so.

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel{
  ...
  public List<EditorViewModel> Lines{get;set;}
  ...
}
```

EditorViewModel.cs

```
public class EditorViewModel{
   ...
   public string Text{get;set;}
   ...
}
```

View.cshtml

```
@model ViewModel
<form>
   ...
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Lines, "Grid")
   ...
</form>
```

EditorTemplates/Grid.cshtml

```
@Model IEnumerable<EditorViewModel>
@Html.Kendo().Grid<EditorViewModel>().BindTo(Model)
...
.Columns(col => {
  col.Bound(m => m.Text)**.EditorTemplate("Text.Grid");**
})
.Editable(g => g.Enabled(true).Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
...
)
```

The Grid is displayed correctly and is editable as excepted, but when I'm leaving the edit mode a javascript error is thrown.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Text' of undefined
at eval (eval at getter (kendo.all.js:2041), <anonymous>:3:21)
at init.set (kendo.all.js:8149)
at init.change (kendo.all.js:8930)
at init.f (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)
at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:124)
at init.window.kendo.window.kendo.devtools.kendo.ui.Widget.trigger (<anonymous>:587:33)
at init._change (kendo.all.js:35754)
at init._blur (kendo.all.js:35719)
at init._focusout (kendo.all.js:35770)
at HTMLInputElement.f (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)
```

Is it possible to use a KendoGrid as Mvc EditorTemplate?
And if it is possible what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

If found a solution for this problem.
Changes made is with bold text.
In the Text.Grid.cshtml you add this line

```
@{
  ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlPrefix = string.Empty;
}
```

this way the property prefix is removed